# Max file upload limitation at jvm or AWS S3 end

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jvm

I am trying to upload a file through **TransferManager(Java)** to AWS S3 bucket.
My question is, if I try to upload a file of approx 4GB, then do I need to handle something at Java end.

Below is the code:

```
File tempFile = AWSUtil.createTempFileFromStream(inputStream);
putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, tempFile);    
final TransferManager transferMgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3client).build();
upload = transferMgr.upload(putObjectRequest);
```

As far as I know AWS S3 has a file upload limitation of 5TB, which is not a concern.

Please let me know if I need to handle it at Java end.

Comment: There is no such limit as far as Java is concerned, but if your example code is part of your web-application and it may be behind the Web-Server like Apache/Nginx, it may have some Max-Body size limit. Is your app Web Application @Rohit?

Comment: Thanks @RedBoy - Application is based on Spring boot's rest web services which will be deployed on embedded tomcat.

Comment: Will it be behind web server like nginx/Apache then proxy pass to Spring boot embedded tomcat?

Comment: No, not for now.

Comment: You are good to assume that you could handle any size files <5TB(S3 limit). It may have some issues in case browser or thick clients drop network connections.